# In US campaign fundraising email, are the "matches" used to encourage giving actually real?

Tags: united-states, fundraising

I receive a great deal of political fundraising email, and I'm often enticed to give by the prospect that my donation will be "matched" by wealthy donors.

And yet, one candidate's website disclosed to monthly givers that their donations could be set aside for a period, instead of spent, to make a "matching amount" that could be used to entice donors like myself.

I am familiar with giving practices, including matching giving: but is use of "the match" in U.S. political emails largely a marketing gimmick?

Comment: Well, what would you accept as “real”? Only if the matching donor gave the money to some other cause, were the matching goal not reached?

Comment: The situation that you're describing sounds like a Ponzi scheme. I'd be surprised if all political campaigns involving matched funding were like this, but I imagine some would be. Without proper research it's going to be difficult to discover just how serious a problem it is.

Comment: A Ponzi scheme is when new deposits are used to pay withdrawals of older deposits.  You can't withdraw political contributions, so there can't be a Ponzi scheme.  And this describes how I would expect matching to work in *any* fundraiser with matching not just political.  It's inherently a marketing gimmick.  Why would you think it was anything else?

Comment: @brythan: Thats why I said 'like' and not 'is'; if there happened to be a name for this kind of financial shennigans that I knew of then I would have used it. Do you happen to know of such a term?

Comment: How do you define "largely a marketing gimmick"? I mean, it is pretty clear that they do not have other objective than encourage more donations, which means that you could directly qualify them as "marketing". Have you answered your own question?

Answer (score 3):

If you already have wealthy donors making donations, it's not unusual that a donor will offer to provide matching donations. So it's almost certainly true that, if they claim a donor is providing $x of matched funding, there is a donor who has agreed to match the given amount.

On the other hand, consider the counterfactual: If a donor offered a campaign to matching donations up to $x and the campaign said they didn't accept that, would they have donated the $x unconditionally instead? I suspect in many cases the answer is yes.